# Photos are not displayed in the wordpress media section when the template is placed on the host

Tags: wordpress, host

Photos are not displayed in the media section when the template is placed on the host

Also, for custom post typing, a link to add an index image is displayed, but the image itself is not displayed

But both of the above works without problems in localhost
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check file permission is set to 755 of uploads folder in wp-content > uploads.
Also check if internal folders of year & month exist with file permissions 755.

File permission should be 755

Comment: no issue-it works with default theme just not working with my own theme

Comment: ok, in that case the issue will be of code conflict with any other plugin or wordpress update. deactivate all the plugins & check.